# Script para abrir chat do aplicativo messenger do facebook

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, facebook

Estou criando um `app`, e queria inserir um botão para abrir uma conversa de uma determinada página do *facebook*, mas pelo aplicativo messenger e não pelo navegador, alguém sabe se tem como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Abrir uma conversa de uma página você quer dizer um post, certo?

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://post/<id_do_post>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Agora se você tiver falando de abrir a fanpage ou perfil de alguém só muda o começo da `URL`, exemplo:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id_da_page_ou_perfil>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Mais opções você pode ver aqui:

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: Essa resposta não é sobre o que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir uma determinada thread no Facebook Messenger basta usar o URL Scheme `fb-messenger://user/{user-id}`. O Parâmetro `user-id` é um *long integer* como pode ser visto em https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/.

Mais informações [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25467446/2305521) resposta do SO (em inglês).

Vale lembrar que a partir do iOS 9 a URL Scheme do Messenger (`fb-messenger`) precisa ser colocada na sua whitelist.

Além disso recomendo que você cheque com `canOpenURL:` primeiro e faça um fallback caso o usuário não possua o messenger instalado.

Comment: Cara, algum tempo atrás eu queria fazer algo parecido com isso. Então acabei encontrando uma solução que serve inclusive para WhatsApp e é mto simples de implementar. Pode ser que te ajude: lucianobragaweb.github.io/integrar-whatsapp-no-site